# A compile-time symbol was #defined but #ifdef does not see it

Tags: c++

I have a test class declared in a header file and defined in a separate file. The class must compile differently under Windows, so i use `#if defined ( _WINDOWS_ )`. When I compile the cpp file which also contains `#if defined ( _WINDOWS_ )`, the file is compiled as if the symbol `_WINDOWS_` was not defined, although it is defined in another file. When I compile the code, I am getting the following error:

> Error Code : error lnk2019 unresolved external symbol public

source code

```
// test.h

class Test
{
public:
#if defined (_WINDOWS_)

void printwindow();
#endif

void notwindows();
}; 

//test.cpp

#include "test.h"

 #if defined (_WINDOWS_)
void Test::printwindow()
{
cout << "i am windows ";
}
 #endif


void test::notwindows()
{
cout << " not windows " ;
}


//main.cpp

#include "windows.h"
#include "test.h"

void main()
{
test t1 ; 

t1.printwindow()  // OK I have declared function so my _WINDOWS_ is available but when i run it i get
}
```

> Error Code : error lnk2019 unresolved external symbol public

NOTE : if i define the function directly it works without any problem

```
// test.h

    class Test
    {
    public:
    #if defined (_WINDOWS_)

    void printwindow(){couT << "i am window" }
    #endif

    void notwindows();
    };
```

but I don't like this method. I prefer to define them in separate files (h and cpp).

Comment: Sorry, this question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @CodyGray: looks like he had to use a machine translator to ask the question. As I see it, he wants certain additional functionality in a class when compiling it under Windows.

Comment: Is this your real code? If it is then the missing `#include <iostream>`, the use of `couT` instead of `cout`, missing a `using namespace std;` (or using std::cout) and the extra colon in the call to `t1.:printwindow()`, the missing semi colon at the end of the line would all cause problems during compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be better for you to use `_WIN32` instead of `_WINDOWS_` for your conditional compilation test.  `_WINDOWS_` is defined only if `windows.h` has been included, while the compiler automatically defines `_WIN32` for any build for a Windows target, regardless of what headers are included. In your situation, `_WINDOWS_` is defined when you compile `main.cpp` but not when you compile `test.cpp` becuase `test.cpp` doesn't include `windows.h`.

Also, the `_WINDOWS_` macro definition is an implementation detail of the `windows.h` header, and is not guaranteed to be used.  For example, the MinGW version of `windows.h` does not define `_WINDOWS_`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include windows.h in your test.cpp file

When you compile test.cpp it does not have the `_WINDOWS_` symbol defined. So it creates an object file without the windows function.

Then in test.hpp it uses the symbol because you included windows.h in main.cpp
If you change the order of the includes it will behave differentially. You should rethink the way how you want to select the windows version which does not depend on the order of includes (for example see the other answer about `_WIN32_`).

You can not change the code in an already compiled object file (test.cpp) using some define in another code file (main.cpp)